# Recommendations for a lisp setup on Mac OS X (any dialect)?

Tags: macos, lisp, scheme, common-lisp

What is your Mac OS X (Intel) based lisp setup (of any dialect), how do you like it, and how painful was it to set up? I'm looking for a versatile lisp that is easy to set up, but if you feel strongly about investing more effort, or even money, I would like to hear why you think it's worth it.

I am currently using [newLisp](http://www.newlisp.org), which was a breeze to set up and gives me simple access to things like graphics and sound. I have heard of SBCL with emacs and slime, but that seems a real pain to set up, and I'm still not friends with emacs. I want to see if there's anything I'm missing out on. I would primarily be using this for pleasure, with no commercial goal in mind.

Please recommend only one setup per answer to enable voting, but feel free to submit multiple answers.

Comment: I also have looked for a non-emacs solution

Answer (score 9):

[Ready Lisp](https://github.com/jwiegley/ready-lisp):

> Ready Lisp is a binding together of several popular Common Lisp packages especially for Mac OS X, including: Aquamacs, SBCL and SLIME. Once downloaded, you’ll have a single application bundle which you can double-click – and find yourself in a fully configured Common Lisp REPL.
>
> It’s ideal for OS X users who want to try out the beauty of Common Lisp with a minimum of hassle. It could also be used by teachers to give their Mac students a free, complete Common Lisp environment to take home with them.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a promising way to get SBCL and slime with a minimum of hassle, and aquamacs is a slightly more gentle emacs...

Comment: FYI. Link is reported as malicious by Google Chrome

Comment: Worth noting that as of March 2023, the last commit to that repo was 14 years ago (March 2009).

Answer (score 7):

The best Lisp for Mac OS X is [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/). It is commercial though. Installation is done with an installer in a few seconds. It is started then with a double-click from the programs folder. It has a Cocoa-Bridge and the user interface is written with it, but based on a portable substrate - so the same development environment is available for Windows and Unix/Linux/FreeBSD.

Comment: I am willing to pay money for hobbies, but the seems VERY steep. Could you tell me why you think it's worth that much? Is it really THAT good, compared to all the many other free alternatives?

Comment: I have a bicycle that is more expensive. Some people have very expensive hobbies.

LispWorks is a very complete implementation with lots of extensions. It can be used in a terminal, with SLIME or with its IDE. It can deliver shrinked applications, does have a cross platform GUI toolkit, database connectivity, etc. It is well supported and I found the 64bit version to be very fast for the Lisp programs I tried. You can either try the personal edition to get a first idea or ask for a trial license of the whole thing.

Edi Weitz for example uses it too to write his libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Rainer. I already have a couple of expensive hobbies (music, photography, mountainbiking) and didn't want to add another, but I may have to give this a try - at least get a trial license to be able to compare it.

Comment: The big difference is, you probably knew how to ride when you bought your bicycle.  If you had the bicycle equivalent of newLisp, you probably wouldn't jump straight to a $1500 bicycle.  :-)

Comment: I have used a lot Lisps over the years, though I wouldn't want to use newLisp, I fear. From the current Lisp implementations the 64bit LispWorks is by far the best, IMHO. The 32bit version is a bit slower. Where people start is their thing. Some people might want to start with something like LispWorks. When I bought me a bicycle for training and competition, I did not start with the low end model. I've updated the components when needed, but the frame is still the same.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "setup".  [Clozure CL](http://trac.clozure.com/openmcl) (previously Open MCL) has an experimental [Cocoa bridge](http://lemonodor.com/archives/images/openmcl-ide-rainer.png), and you can even build a smallish IDE as well (just fire it up and do a (require "COCOA-APPLICATION") and it'll build the .app bundle for you).  I use vim myself, but you're free to use whatever editor you like (+ Interface Builder), of course.  CCL *supports* Emacs+Slime, but does not require it.

Comment: If you intend to use the CCL IDE, you may want to check out trunk rather than a stable release because there's been a lot of recent IDE work on the trunk.

Answer (score 5):

Try [PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/). It is mature, has lot of libraries and comes with an IDE.

Answer (score 4):

[Gambit scheme](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a "complete, portable, efficient and reliable implementation of the Scheme programming language":

> Gambit consists of two main programs: gsi, the Gambit Scheme interpreter, and gsc, the Gambit Scheme compiler. The interpreter contains the complete execution and debugging environment. The compiler is the interpreter extended with the capability of generating executable files. The compiler can produce standalone executables or compiled modules which can be loaded at run time.

The Gambit compiler allows Scheme to be compiled to C, with some pretty cool applications, like writing an [iPhone app](http://jlongster.com/blog/2009/06/17/write-apps-iphone-scheme/) in Scheme (with a [REPL](http://jlongster.com/blog/2009/07/5/remotely-debugging-iphone-scheme/) for remote debugging).

There is a FFI for Gambit so you can use [external C libraries](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Using_Gambit_with_External_Libraries).

There is an [installer](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/download/gambit/v4.5/prebuilt/gambc-v4_5_1-macosx-intel32.dmg) or you can install via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You could install [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html). I'd use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/).

That is easy, but it gives you a fairly lightweight scheme installation.

Comment: Cool, the first answer to my question and already a scheme that I haven't heard of yet! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**General Comments**

Most lisps are not that hard to set up on OS X if you're used to working on the command line, though some are harder than others. I think the hardest to set up are CMUCL and Clozure; if memory serves, you need to make a symbolic link into a directory on your path if you don't want to run them from their respective directories (they don't install an executable into /usr/local/bin on installation). In any case, you'll put more work into getting Slime going in Emacs than you will actually installing a lisp. New Lisp is an easy install from the OS X gui, installed from a OS X package (making it the easiest install of all lisps except, perhaps, for PLT Scheme).

I do recommend using a some form of IDE, be it Emacs + Slime or the LispWorks or Clozure IDEs. People use other editors, but those are the ones that have been tailored most to programming in lisp. Personally, I wouldn't enjoy programming in lisp if I couldn't use Emacs + Slime, but I've put in a lot of time to learn the Emacs and Slime commands.

**Implementation Recommendation**

Here is a specific recommendation that is different from the others. If you are new to lisp and not too picky that it be Common Lisp, you should look at [PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/). It comes with an IDE and an implementation (DrScheme and mzscheme) that can't be beat for ease of installation and use for a beginner. PLT Scheme comes with lots of extensions to Scheme that make is easier to use for more programming tasks than the other Schemes as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does seem like there's a high entry barrier with emacs, but it also seems that most people that invest this time think it was worth it...

Comment: It's a godsend. I use the DrScheme IDE to teach programming to a friend's teenager, and I always feel inefficient now using it --- I have to take my fingers away from the keyboard far too much when using DrScheme. It's also frustrating not to have Emacs' powerful editing commands at your disposal when using DrScheme (I sometimes fire up emacs to properly structure data taken from elsewhere rather than waste my time fixing it up in DrScheme). 

That being said, if you're not yet attached to Emacs and CL I strongly recommend PLT Scheme while you're still feeling your way around.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: (assumes you have the excellent Mac Ports installed)

Step 1:

$ sudo port install mit-scheme

Step 2:

$ scheme

Step 3:

Read Structure and Interpretation
of Computer Programs http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Answer (score 0):

Clojure is a wonderful lisp. it is truly modern lisp designed for pragmatic concurrent programming. It compiles to the JVM and can call and be called by java nativity with no wrapping and a minimum of ceremony.

```
clojure.org
```

Answer (score 0):

try: XMLisp for OS X (FOSS)

3D: Open Agent Engine: scene graph based mini engine, 3D objects, animation, mouse hovering, selection, camera control, texture management
2D: controls: layout managers, buttons, sliders, text

http://code.google.com/p/xmlisp/

It is an extension of Clozure CL. IDE is included. You should be able to get this running in no time.

Alex